# Nested List of Custom Object. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-2010, nested-lists

I'm new to VB.net and requires your help.
I've two vb.net Structures, Quotation and FareAsPerVehicleType, Quotation is dependent on FareAsPerVehicleType. I am trying to add VehicleType in Quotation by using the following:

```
Dim Quot As New Quotation
Dim vT As FareAsPerVehicleType
    vT.TypeOfVehicle = "S"
    vT.Fare = _raw_Price * vF.Saloon_Factor
Quot.VehicleType.Add(vT)

Public Structure FareAsPerVehicleType
    Dim TypeOfVehicle As String
    Dim Fare As Decimal
End Structure

Public Structure Quotation
    Dim VehicleType As List(Of FareAsPerVehicleType)
    Dim Mileage As Decimal
    Dim TimeToTravel As Decimal
    Dim Pickup As String
    Dim Dropoff As String
End Structure
```

In doing so I am getting the following error.

```
<"System.NullReferenceException was unhandled">
<"  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.">
<"  Source=WindowsApplication1">
```

Please help
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the collection before you can use it.  As is, when you are declaring a new Quotation object, the VehicleType list is set to nothing.  Change the declaration line to

```
Dim VehicleType As New List(Of FareAsPerVehicleType)
```

Or even better, change to declaration to remove the Dim and replace with Public to show the accessibility of the field.

```
Public VehicleType As New List(Of FareAsPerVehicleType)
```

To really make the code shine, you could replace the field with an auto property:

```
Public Property VehicleType() As New List(Of FareAsPerVehicleType)
```

Any of these will work to get rid of your error.